# How to merge nested arrays on parent id

Tags: javascript, arrays, merge

I am trying to merge a 2D array that has duplicate header information.

In the following example it would be merging item `three` into the array with items `one` and `two`, and also merging item `five` with item `four`.

**Example Data**

```
let data = [{
  header: {
    id: 1
  }, 
  items: [{
    item: 'one'
  }, {
    item: 'two'
  }]
}, {
  header: {
    id: 1
  }, 
  items: [{
    item: 'three'
  }]
}, {
  header: {
    id: 2
  }, 
  items: [{
    item: 'four'
  }]
}, {
  header: {
    id: 2
  }, 
  items: [{
    item: 'five'
  }]
}]

let i, j, l = data.length;
for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
  let m = data[i]['items'].length;
  for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {
    if (data[i]['header']['id'] === data[i + 1]['header']['id']) {
      // merge records
    }
  }
}
```

I'm not sure how to do a proper comparison in the `if` block since `i + 1` will end up longer than `data[i]['items'].length`, and see a similar issue with trying to merge.

**Expected Output**

```
let data = [{
  header: {
    id: 1
  }, 
  items: [{
    item: 'one'
  }, {
    item: 'two'
  }, {
    item: 'three'
  }]
}, {
  header: {
    id: 2
  }, 
  items: [{
    item: 'four'
  }, {
    item: 'five'
  }]
}]
```

Here you can see that the expected output merges together `1,2,3` and `4,5` on `id`.

How can I merge all like items together based on a header `id`?

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to make an intermediate object to track which headers have been encountered from the input array, with the value being the items found for that header. Once the map is created you can convert it into an array:

```js
let data = [...];
let mergeMap = {};

data.forEach(entry => {
    mergeMap[entry.header.id] = [
        ...(mergeMap[entry.header.id] || []),
        ...entry.items
    ]
});

const merged = Object.keys(mergeMap).map(header => ({
    header,
    items: mergeMap[key]
}))
```

Comment: Is the `key` `header.id`?

Comment: Yes the key would be header.id.

Comment: Nice! OK, I'll have to dig in a bit more. I'm getting `[header: [object Object], items: undefined]`.

Comment: It looks like the `header` data isn't retained in the `mergeMap`.

Comment: So, the header object is slightly more complicated, like `{header: {id: 1, data: { obj_data }}`. Is there a way to use this method to retain the object structure so it doesn't compute to `[object Object]`?

Comment: It throws an error when trying to merge on `mergeMap[JSON.parse(entry.order)]`.

Comment: Yes it is possible to use objects as keys in a WeakMap - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap

Comment: Hm. Still having issues when declaring `let data = new WeakMap()`. But the general idea is to have a normalization and denormalization step?

Answer (score 0):

Can do this with a Set and a Map call.

We use the Set to create an array with only unique `header` ids

```
    const merged = [...new Set(data.map(({ header: { id }}) => id))]
```

At this point we have an array with unique header ID. `[1,2]` based on the sample data.

Now we can call `map` over this array and pull the data from our original array.

```js
const data = [{
  header: {
    id: 1
  },
  items: [{
    item: 'one'
  }, {
    item: 'two'
  }]
}, {
  header: {
    id: 1
  },
  items: [{
    item: 'three'
  }]
}, {
  header: {
    id: 2
  },
  items: [{
    item: 'four'
  }]
}, {
  header: {
    id: 2
  },
  items: [{
    item: 'five'
  }]
}];

// The set gives us unique headers. And then we can map data.
const merged = [...new Set(data.map(({ header: { id }}) => id))]
                .map(id => ({
                  header: {
                    id
                  },
                  items: data.filter(({
                      header: {
                        id: i
                      }
                    }) => i === id)
                    .flatMap(({
                      items: i
                    }) => i)
                }));

console.log(merged);
```